# Gif is not Loading in Safari

Tags: css, safari

Loading GIF is not working in Safari Browser.. :(

```
<style>
    #divLoading {
        display : none;
    }
    #divLoading.show {
        display : block;
        position : fixed;
        z-index: 100;
        background-image : url('<?php echo base_url('assets/logo/loading2.gif'); ?>');
        background-color:#666;
        opacity : 0.4;
        background-repeat : no-repeat;
        background-position : center;
        left : 0;
        bottom : 0;
        right : 0;
        top : 0;
    }

    #loadinggif.show {
        left : 50%;
        top : 50%;
        position : absolute;
        z-index : 101;
        width : 32px;
        height : 32px;
        margin-left : -16px;
        margin-top : -16px;
    }

    div.content {
       width : 1000px;
       height : 1000px;
    }
</style>
<div id="divLoading"></div>
```

Loading GIF is not Working in Safari Browser.. :(
But it perfectly works in Chrome..

Jfiddle Link :
https://jsfiddle.net/sadhique92/b3fkwxg5/

Comment: What version of Safari do you use? It works for me in Safari 10.

Comment: Yes with safari 10 works.

Comment: @Joker: were you able to fix this problem?

Comment: @Joker, what version of Safari and OS are you running? I see the loader just fine in Safari 12.0.3.